# IIS Hosted WCF Service schemaLocation Address Issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I have a service hosted in IIS 7 on a separate web server in my local network. I have the service accessible on the Internet. One thing is bothering me and I can't solve it.

When I check the wsdl of the service, I see that the schemaLocation address is set to the machine name of the server and not the domain name the service is assigned to. I tried changing the baseAddress to the domain name but it doesn't change a thing. But when I change the baseAddress to the IP address of the server schemaLocation changes.

What do I need to configure so that the schemaLocation on the wsdl would use the domain name set for the service?

Answer (score 1):

In your serviceMetadata tag, there is an attribute you can set called httpGetUrl, like this:

```
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">
<serviceMetaData httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="your-complete-url-here"/>
</behavior>
```

That will set it for you.

http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/domain-name-replaced-with-machine-name.html

Edit: There's also a httpsGetUrl to use if your service is secured (you didnt say)